# Send AWS S3 notification only once for many files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-sns

I have enabled the S3 notification `create:*` event for SNS sending to my email from AWS CLI in my Windows servers.

However, there are many notification emails received from the SNS after I copied 10000+ local files such as xml, html, jpg to the S3. Because of creating the folder or the files, it is going to send the event with per creating file request to SNS.

I search the topic discussed in Edit event notification prefix and suffix and I think it just partially works on folder and file.

How can just receive one notification email that indicates it's starting the copy job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can just receive one notification email that indicates it's starting the copy job?

**You can't**. This is not how S3 notifications work. You would have to develop custom solution to that. Maybe instead of SNS, have a lambda function to get triggered. The function would somehow verify if this is the first file being uploaded, and send out email only for that file.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response